# Problem with gnome-tweak-tool running from applications menu

Tags: debian, ubuntu, gnome

i have gnome-tweak tool running on a install of Debian 8 with gdm3 installed, how do i allow this application to run with full permissions? When i run "sudo gnome-tweak-tool" the program runs as expected, but when i try to run some programs from the applications menu or just using the app name without sudo from terminal, there are problems. With gnome-tweak-tool it runs but it's not possible to change anything, and it opens with a theme different to the system theme.
I don't have this problem on Ubuntu gnome, could someone please explain why that would be, what am i missing, how do i fix it without adding sudo or gksu to the exec line of every .desktop file?

This is what i expect to happen:

[image]

Here's what's actually happening without running with sudo from terminal:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with gnome install.

I ran these commands in the terminal;

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install gdm3 -y
sudo apt-get --reinstall install gnome -y
sudo apt-get --reinstall install gnome-shell -y
```

Now `gnome-tweak-tool` works fine when launched from the applications menu.

Answer (score 0):

First try to find what is going wrong. Run gnome-tweaks from terminal simply typing gnome-tweaks in the terminal. In Tweak will make some changes and see the log in the terminal. If it says

> Cannot open dconf database: invalid gvdb header

~/.config/dconf/user* files might have corrupted. Try the following command, it should recreate a new one and allow you to store your settings persistently:

```
mv ~/.config/dconf/ ~/.config/dconf.bak
```

Note that you may loose some customization that you may have set on your system as all of them will be reset.

If it does not solve your problem all you have to do is:

```
mv ~/.config/dconf.bak ~/.config/dconf/
```